# How to properly insert windbg breakpoints on mshtml and MS IE 11?

Tags: function, reverse-engineering, windbg, internet-explorer-11

I'm digging into MS Internet explorer 11 and mshtml.dll, lets be fast & clear : I'm investigating the "CTitleElement" class of "mshtml.dll" on windows 8.1, I want to set breakpoints on some functions in "CTitleElement" class to see what's going on inside this class (e.g : creating title element, getting title, setting title, getting title's length, etc ...)

I used windbg to attach the IE process, and here's what I did to set breakpoints :

```
0:013> bp MSHTML!CTitleElement::GetTitle
0:013> bp MSHTML!CTitleElement::SetTitle
0:013> bp MSHTML!CTitleElement::s_StringTable
0:013> bp MSHTML!CTitleElement::CreateElement
0:013> bp MSHTML!CTitleElement::TitleLength
```

and then running into IE with "g" command & opening the following simple html file :

```
<html>
    <title>Hello There!</title>
</html>
```

but unfortunately, I did not get the desirable result, the debugger did not hit the breakpoints .
As I noticed, it's an unstable situation, because : "sometimes it got hit & sometimes not!"

I was think of ASLR and the type of breakpoint I just set ("bp"), disabled ASLR by installing EMET & disabling all memory protections, but I still unable to get the result in a reliable manner .

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

regards.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting breakpoints in correct process? IE is notorious for spawning child iexplore.exe processes for every tab and probably different HTML frames, so you might see multiple processes per tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ASLR has got anything to do here. You are setting the break points using function names and not addresses. The addresses can change but the function names would still remain the same :)

1. to ensure that you do not miss out because of the child processes created by IE (as mentioned by Sesa)

   - Launch windbg.
   - From the file menu choose "Open Executable" OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
   - give the path of iexplorer.
   - make sure you have option "Debug Child Processes also" checked.
2. make sure you have the symbols correctly loaded.
3. To ensure your break-points persist across debugging sessions use "bu" instead of bp.
   check that all break-points show up everytime using "bl"

Answer (score 0):

I'm just speculating what is going on. Perhaps when you first load the page in IE it fully renders it. Next time, the page may not be fully rendered because the result of previous run used and an other code path is executed that doesn't hit your breakpoint.

Did you try force refresh Ctrl+F5?